# Xamarin Studio monomac crashes when open interface builder

Tags: xcode

When I open interface builder from Xamarin Studio it crashes. I have tried to install Xcode many times but it still doesn't work. The crash log is below.

I hope someone who knows a solution. Thanks!

```
Process:         Xcode [1626]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5.2 (1847)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1847000000000000~5
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [418]
Responsible:     Xcode [1626]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2013-11-26 13:59:17.187 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  AF32F1BF-E83F-B6FF-06FD-D8E115910A47


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G2008a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-2844/CocoaIntegration/Inspectors/Effects/Inspectors/IBCIFilterEffectsInspector.m:149
Details:  code which should be unreachable has been reached
Object:   <IBContentFiltersEffectsInspector: 0x402dd9060>
Method:   -inspectorXMLForFilter:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40040a2a0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```